# How to get previous 4 week sales at a level

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-rolling

I would like to find previous four week sales at a level in Python. Say for example

```
ID  Category    Date    Sales
1   AA  7/02/2022   1
1   AA  31/01/2022  3
1   AA  24/01/2022  5
1   AA  10/01/2022  7
1   AA  03/01/2022  9
2   BB  7/02/2022   2
2   BB  31/01/2022  4
2   BB  24/01/2022  6
2   BB  17/01/2022  8
2   BB  10/01/2022  10
```

For 1 AA 7/02/2022 sum of last four weeks will be 9 (as 17/01/2022 bales is not there and must include current row date)

Comment: Yes, it’s pandas data frame

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, you can keep the [tag:python] tag :-). But we need the [tag:pandas] tag too.

Comment: Added pandas tag too

Comment: Yep, all good now

Comment: Please improve this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the date as index, groupby Category and take the sum of a 28-day rolling window of Sales:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = '''ID  Category    Date    Sales
1   AA  7/02/2022   1
1   AA  31/01/2022  3
1   AA  24/01/2022  5
1   AA  10/01/2022  7
1   AA  03/01/2022  9
2   BB  7/02/2022   2
2   BB  31/01/2022  4
2   BB  24/01/2022  6
2   BB  17/01/2022  8
2   BB  10/01/2022  10'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

result_df = df.set_index('Date').sort_index().groupby('Category')['Sales'].rolling("28D").sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

|  | Category | Date | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AA | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 9 |
| 1 | AA | 2022-01-10 00:00:00 | 16 |
| 2 | AA | 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 21 |
| 3 | AA | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | 15 |
| 4 | AA | 2022-02-07 00:00:00 | 9 |
| 5 | BB | 2022-01-10 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 6 | BB | 2022-01-17 00:00:00 | 18 |
| 7 | BB | 2022-01-24 00:00:00 | 24 |
| 8 | BB | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | 28 |
| 9 | BB | 2022-02-07 00:00:00 | 20 |

Comment: This helped, Thank you! Could you please tell me how I can do the above but exclude current week sales i.e., for 2 BB 07/02/2022 - sum of sales should be 28 (excluding current date and going back 28 days).